# ListView: hide Contextual Action Bar

Tags: android, listview, android-contextmenu, multichoiceitems

I'm following the [official guide for using contextual action mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB) like this:

```
    listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.shelf_context, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            // some processing...
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }
    });
```

My listView is inside a `Fragment` which is inside a `ViewPager`, so I want to hide the Contextual Action Bar when the fragment becomes invisible. But how do I do that? I call `listView.clearChoices()` to clear the selection, but the CAB is still visible:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (!isVisibleToUser) {
        listView.clearChoices(); // CAB is still visible.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found a hacky way to do that:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (!isVisibleToUser) {
        listView.clearChoices();
        listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL); // this strange hack dismisses the CAB.
    }
}
```

Comment: can u share your code? that's not working for me..!!

Answer (score 5):

`mode.finish()` isn't working?

```
case R.id.action_remove:
    mode.finish();
```

Comment: How about this?
1. save the mode in `onCreateActionMode()` like `mActionMode = mode`
2. call the `mActionMode.finish()` in `setUserVisibleHint()`